# Washing machine (Electrolux, front loader) motor is heating up

Tags: washing-machine, electric-motor

Recently I've changed the drum bearings on my now 13 year-old washing machine. All went fine, the drum spins properly but at the end of a program, there's a noticeable burnt-like smell that wasn't there before. Also the motor doesn't stop, IDK if it's because it doesn't have a overheating protection or it didn't hit its threshold. But when I took down the motor, it was piping hot. Tried to clean the brushes, the carbon lint it was gathering, look that the pads, they're OK, the brushes (L93MF7) still have 17mm in length and their number is visible, they also slide well and seat well. So I don't know why, as it seems, the stator would get this hot. The spade connectors were pushed in as much as they allow, same on the board. Any tips?

Comment: Are you sure the bearings are in properly and everything is lined up?  Something mounted too tight or too loose or missing the small washer that you did not see.  Motor might just be at its end of life.

Comment: Yes, the bearings are good, the drum moves easily and without issues. "Too tight" doesn't   fit as the assembly isn't ajustable, the motos sits in its place and that's it. Judging by the wear of the brushed I doubt the motor has an issue... I was thinking wiring, lose spade connectors, split wires etc.

Comment: Insulation might be breaking down on the winding(piping hot, burnt smell) or motor bearings are going.

Comment: Was the drive belt replaced at the same time? Could it be too tight? When you say the drum spins easily, is that without the belt on, or do the drum and motor spin easily together?

Comment: Well, it can't be too tight since it's not adjustable. However, after each load I would manually spin the tumbler for 'sticky socks' and after 10 years of doing so I got a feeling of how easy it should spin. There's no discernible difference to it. Without the belt it goes a lot longer.

Comment: I mounted a temp probe on the motor. I got 35 *C after 60 min, 45ish *C after 120 and about 55 *C after 180 min, the longest program that it has. Would 55*C be too hot? It's about then (after about 2 1/2 hours) when the smell becomes noticeable.